# Ordering results by how many duplicates are returned

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query:

`select titles.* from titles left join quotes on quotes.title_id = titles.id where titles.type = 4 order by titles.slug DESC`

This returns multiple duplicate title records. I'd like to count how many duplicate `title.slugs` there are and order by most to least.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the purpose of Joining on `quotes` table. You dont seem to use it anywhere!

Comment: Sample data with expected output would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of this was to pull instances where the foreign key was used. The left join ensures that the foreign key is not null. The rest is done by using COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING,

Like so:

`select titles.*, count(*) as n from titles left join quotes on quotes.title_id = titles.id where titles.type = 4 GROUP BY slug HAVING n > 1 order by n DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `group by` with `order by aggregate`:

```
SELECT titles.*
FROM titles 
LEFT JOIN quotes 
    ON quotes.title_id = titles.id 
WHERE titles.type = 4 
GROUP BY titles.slug
ORDER BY COUNT(titles.slug) DESC
```

if you need to use the duplicate count add something like this to your `select` statement:

```
COUNT(titles.slug) as duplicate_title_count
```

Also, there's no point to join the table here.. or are you plan on selecting something from it?